# Angular Materials 2: How to globally set a theme color to an element?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Is there a way to globally set a theme color for all buttons in my application? (I do not want to change the Angular Material theme I just want to be able to globally apply it)

I am using Angular 6 with Angular Materials 2.

I am utilizing the materials themes.

Currently I can accomplish this for each button by setting the color to primary/accent:

```
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close [mat-dialog-close]="true" tabindex="0" mat-primary color="primary">My Awesome Button</button>
```

However I would like to be able to globally set this so that I just add 
`<button>Click Me</button>` and it would automatically use the primary theme color.

In my styles.css I tried to set it this way but it does not recognize the "primary" value.

```
.button {
  color: primary;
}
```

EDIT:
Actually tried.

```
button {
  color: primary;
}
```

Comment: you dont have a button class

Comment: That was a typo.  Let me edit.

Comment: it is not possible to add your variable inside .css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button mat-button mat-dialog-close [mat-dialog-close]="true" tabindex="0" >My Awesome Button</button>
```

In your styles.css use `mat-button` selector

```
.mat-button{
background: #ffd740;//accent//you can customize it accordingly
}
```

[`Demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-miproz)

Comment: Not the solution I was hoping for, but this does work.